# How can I get specific information from an external api to my ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

### main.html

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="post in myBlogPosts.slice().reverse()">
    <br>
    <div class="col-md-9 text-center">
        <a href="#/blog-post/{{post._id}}">
            <div class="thumbnail mTextBg customShadow">
                <br>
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placekitten.com/700/400" alt="">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h3>{{post.imdbId}}</h3>
                    <p>{{post.blogContent}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">


        // I WANT THIS PART !!
        <div class="well sideBars customShadow">
            <img class="img-responsive" ng-src="{{film.Poster}}" title="{{film.Title}}">
            <h4 class="text-center">{{film.Title}}</h4>
            <p class="text-center" style="margin-bottom: 2px;"><b>Year:</b> {{film.Year}}</p>
            <p class="text-center"><span class="customMargin">Runtime: {{film.Runtime}}</span></p>
            <p class="text-center"><span class="customMargin">Director: {{film.Director}}</span></p>
            <p class="text-center"><span class="customMargin">Writer: {{film.Writer}}</span></p>
            <p class="text-center"><span class="customMargin">Actors: {{film.Actors}}</span></p>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

This is part of my main.html . In h3 and p tags, I get imdbId and blogContent from my database and put it in ng-repeat in order to traverse blog posts in list. I want to be able get other information(under **// I WANT THIS PART**) for every post in myBlogPost.

### MainController.js

```
var refresh = function() {
  $http.get('/myDatabase').success(function(response) {
    $scope.myBlogPosts = response;
  });
};

refresh();
```

This part work as expected when page loaded.

I need also these parts in Main Controller ;

```
var onGetFilmData = function (data) {
  $scope.film = data;
};

var onError = function (reason) {
  $scope.error = reason;
};

imdb.getImdbInfo(-- need Id --).then(onGetFilmData, onError);
```

But I need to put each post id somehow in order to get specific data from Imdb api.

### Imdb.js

```
(function(){
  
  var imdb = function($http){

    var getImdbInfo = function (id) {
      return $http.get('http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=' + id + '&plot=short&r=json')
                  .then(function(response){
                    return response.data;
                  });
    };
    
    return{
      getImdbInfo: getImdbInfo
    };
    
  };
  
  var module = angular.module('myApp');
  module.factory('imdb', imdb);
  
})();
```

If I delete *id* part and put a specific id string in getImdbInfo function, all post in main.html fill with just one film information. I want to fetch those data for each film in my database(I am holding imdb id of each film in my database).

Answer (score 0):

**MainController**

```
var jsonObj = {};

var refresh = function() {
  $http.get('/myDatabase').success(function(response) {

    jsonObj = response;

    for(var i = 0; i < jsonObj.length ; i++){
        jsonObj[i].title = '';
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < jsonObj.length ; i++){
      (function(i) {
        imdb.getImdbInfo(jsonObj[i].imdbId).then(function (data) {  
          jsonObj[i].title = data.Title;
        });
      })(i);

    }

    $scope.myBlogPosts = jsonObj;
  });
};

refresh();
```

**main.html**

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="post in myBlogPosts.slice().reverse()">
    <br>
    <div class="col-md-9 text-center">
        <a href="#/blog-post/{{post._id}}">
            <div class="thumbnail mTextBg customShadow">
                <br>
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placekitten.com/700/400" alt="">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h3>{{post.imdbId}}</h3>
                    <p>{{post.blogContent}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">


        <!-- Side Widget Well -->
            <div class="well sideBars customShadow">
                <h4 class="text-center">{{post.title}}</h4>
            </div>    
    </div>
</div>
```

I solve my problem with adding response from Imdb to my json object which is coming from database. So I can easily use them in ng-repeat.